# Why does my Regular expression "searching" for words in a sentence include the punctuation immediately preceding the word

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using a regular expression to find a list of words in a sentence like this:

`let $str = '(\\W(like|the|is|it))\\b';`

`let $re = new RegExp($str, 'gi');`

There are normally a lot more words, but I've shortened the list for ease of reading.

So now if I had a sentence such as 'I like to go out' it would match like this 'I **like** to go out'.

However, if I have a sentence with punctuation in it PRECEDING the word (with no space) it will also match that. Meaning the sentence 'I am "the man' would match like this: 'I am **"the** man'

The problem seems to be that the word boundary goes to the space left of the word. Which is acceptable. But for some reason it *includes* the punctuation if its there as well. Only to the left though.

If I have the sentence 'I am "the" man' it would match like this: 'I am **"the**" man.

Eventually I **do** need the punctuation on *both* sides to be captured , but it only captures the preceding character, not the following character. So I'm doing a second regular expression to then match the other punctuation. But doing it that way leaves me with the preceding characters being matched twice...

`let $str2 = '(\\.|,|!|\\?|\")+';`

`let $re2 = new RegExp($str2, 'g');`

To briefly explain the end result: I am wrapping (with a JS replace) the matched words in html tags so they receive a specific style.

```
let $str = '(\\W(like|the|is|it))\\b';
let $re = new RegExp($str, 'gi');
text = text.replace($re, "<mark>$&</mark>");


let $str2 = '(\\.|,|!|\\?|\")+';
let $re2 = new RegExp($str2, 'g');
text = text.replace($re2, "<mark>$&</mark>");
```

If I run the sentence 'I am "the" man.' through this it would return this:

```
I am<mark> <mark>"</mark>the</mark>" man<mark>.</mark>
```

Which is *not* the desired outcome. The desired outcome would be this (2 total marks):

```
I am <mark>"the"</mark> man<mark>.</mark>
```

Or this (with tags individually around each quote AND the word leaving me with 4 total marks:

```
I am <mark>"</mark><mark>the</mark><mark>"</mark> man<mark>.</mark>
```

No marks should be *inside* other marks.

If I'm not clear, or more/ different examples would help, let me know. I tried to be as specific as possible.

**EDIT: ** I've had a few questions about using a string to define the regex. I'm doing it because in my real code the words list is a variable so it actually looks like this: `let $str = '(\\W('+ words +'))\\b';`

I don't think I can put a variable like that into a regex literal? Can I?

Comment: Can you show us the entirety of the regex?

Comment: This feels like two problems, one right after the other. The question in the title (left/right asymmetry) is essentially contained in `let $str = '(\\W(like|the|is|it))\\b';`, but then the bit with `<mark>` sounds like a slightly-different question.

Comment: It sounds like you want [balanced capture groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html)?

Comment: *"it would match like this 'I **like** to go out'."* No, the match is `' like'`, including the whitespace. The same way it includes any other non-word character preceding your word

Comment: Why define the regular expression with a string?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Probably a lack of knowledge.  It wasn't super obvious when I was learning js that you could declare regex like `let re = /myregex/gi`

Comment: @Thomas correct, I just couldn't really bold the space as well. But well noted that it is any non-word character. It would just be that the style doesn't apply to the space, so I didn't catch it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It isn't specifically clear in my question (I'll edit it now) but the reason I'm using a string is because the words list is a variable. So I'm actually doing it like this: ```let $str = '(\\W('+ words +'))\\b';```

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/Jd29sf/1, try https://jsfiddle.net/254c5ncv/

Answer (score 2):

> Why does my Regular expression “searching” for words in a sentence include the punctuation immediately preceding the word

Because you have `\W` in your regex, so it gets matched. `\W` [means](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

> Matches any non-word character. Equivalent to `[^A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Later you said:

> Eventually I do need the punctuation on both sides to be captured

In that case, include a `\W` on both sides, perhaps (to handle leading a trailing examples) in an alternation with `^` and `$`. Also, no need for a capture group if you're replacing the entire match:

```js
let $str = '(?:^|\\W)like|the|is|it(?:\\W|$)';
let $re = new RegExp($str, 'gi');
let text = 'I am "the" man';
text = text.replace($re, "<mark>$&</mark>");
console.log(text);
```

**That said**, I suspect you don't really want `\W`, you probably want a class of punctuation characters that you want captured (`["']` perhaps), since `\W` matches a space or a comma, which you probably don't want to wrap.

---

Side note: Unless you have a good reason for using a string to define the regular expression, I'd suggest using a regular expression literal instead. That way, you don't have to worry about escaping backslashes in tokens like `\W`:

```
let $re = /(?:^|\W)like|the|is|it(?:\W|$)/gi;
```

Comment: Per your side note: I'm editing my question to clarify, but I'm using a string first because i'm actually adding the words in as a variable. Like this: ```let $str = '(\\W('+ words +'))\\b';``` Unless I can do that in a regex literal (which I don't *think* I can?) (Also, I'm testing your other suggestions now, will reply momentarily)

Comment: @OscarWilde: That makes sense. :-)

Comment: this is close, and I think you're likely right that using \W on both sides instead of doing 2 separate expressions might be the better way to go. However, I *do* want to include the spaces on either side so I tried this: ```(\W(like|the|is|it)\W)\b``` and it gives me a really close result, but it doesn't always capture.

I think to express exactly what it should match would look like this (in English)

Before the word: A space or punctuation char.
WORD
After the word: A space or punctuation char.

So "\_like." and "\_like\_" and ".like." would all match... Is that possible?

Comment: @OscarWilde: `\W` would do that, because it matches a space or a punctuation character (and anything else that isn't in `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`). To narrow it down, again, use a character class, such as `[ .,"'?!]`.